# Getting the requested resource from login

Tags: symfony

I'm looking to get the requested resource from the login page.

So if e.g:

- User goes into `/admin?foo=1&bar=2`
- User gets redirected to /login, [Symfony knows to redirect to the requested resource](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-success) after successful login.
- The problem: In my `login.html.twig`, how can I access the requested resource ( `/admin?foo=1&bar=2` ) from the twig template?

Reasoning for this is that I want to pass the requested resource to the registration form so that in I can redirect the user to `/admin?foo=1&bar=2` right after a successful registration - and the user will then login and automatically get to `/admin?foo=1&bar=2`.

Thanks

Comment: Please use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`, write it to session, or pass it to form, and after successful login redirect to that URL.

Comment: But, as you wrote, aren't things already working this way ?

Answer (score 0):

In the routing controller method (e.g. `LoginController::loginAction()`) you should have access to the “target path”:

```
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('_security.secured_area.target_path')
```

Not that, depending on your SF2 version, the `_security.secured_area.target_path` part may be a bit different.

This is indeed similar to the HTTP_REFERER, but it is stored in the session and therefore still available if e.g. the user reloads the page.